# Why does SCCM report Windows IE v11 as v18?

Tags: internet-explorer, sccm

Internet Explorer v11 is on all the machines. However, SCCM reports it as v18. I've performed various Google searches and can't seem to find anything on it. Has anyone ever seen this before? I would also like to know what is causing it and how to resolve it. I'm using SCCM version 18.2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone ever seen this before?

Internet Explorer 11 is handled differently on Windows 10.  What you see is absolutely normal.  Each version of Windows 10 has it's own build of Internet Explorer 11.

> I would also like to know what is causing it and how to resolve it.

SCCM is picking up on your Windows 10 build.  Which is the reason it's 18.00.16299.492 instead of the IE11 build that exists on Windows 7 or Windows 8.1.

Comment: It appears your Windows 10 installation is [8 months out of date](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4284819) by the way.

Comment: Reading your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756885/why-does-sccm-report-windows-ie-v11-as-v18) it also might be a bug in SCCM and/or the report itself.  However, IE11 is handled differently on Windows 10, the build of IE11 does indeed change between Windows 10 versions.  I would try and update SCCM to the current version and perform the scan again.

Comment: I was thinking that was the case because the last portion of it was the Windows 10 build from June 12, 2018 16299.492

Comment: While I suspect the major version should still be reported as 11 (at least that is the case with my 1709 installation within the IE11 about dialog), and thus the report is not identifying that portion correctly, the minor build number, should match the minor build number of Windows.

Comment: That is correct the major version should be reported as 11 (and it is on our sccm 1810 so it is some sort of bug). As i commented on the other question the information likely comes from the iexplore.exe file directly and is the ProductVersion stored there but how or why it gets changed I dunno (I had a crazy idea first that it might be some super weird HEX to DEC interpretation but then it would be 17 not 18 (and also file versions are strings anyway so doubly weird))